# Unidentified Process Bound to Port 80

Tags: iis, binding

I'm trying to hunt down a reason that IIS can't bind port 80. Here's the path to the question:

1. I received an error from my reporting platform that said "Web Services - Necessary network binding may already be in use, Web site has been disabled"
2. A netstat -abo said that it was in use by PID 4:

   Proto       Local Address          Foreign Address        State      PID

   TCP    0.0.0.0:80             *MyServerNameHere*:0        LISTENING     4

   Can not obtain ownership information
3. The Task Manager says that PID 4 is "NT Kernel & System"
4. Port 80 is not double-bound in the website properties in IIS manager

At this point I'm out of tricks. How do I figure out what I have to disable to release the binding so I can start the website.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your "reporting platform"? A site on IIS? Conflicts among site bindings and Windows HTTP API are rather common, so you shouldn't look elsewhere but your IIS configuration and Windows HTTP API (like [this](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls)).

Answer (score 0):

You should determine which sites are using the same bindings. Then, modify the bindings as needed, and restart the site.

- Determine which sites are using the same bindings

  1.Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Administrative Tools.

  2.Right-click Internet Information Services Manager and select Run as administrator.

  3.In the IIS Manager Connections pane, expand the computer name.

  4.Left-click the Sites folder. A list of the Web sites on the server appears on the right in Features View. The binding for each site is listed in the Binding column.

  5.Review the list of bindings and look for sites that have the same binding properties set, look for two sites that both have a binding of *:80 (http).
- Remove the duplicate binding

  1.In IIS Manager, in the Connections pane, select the Web site that you have to configure.

  2.In the Actions pane, click Bindings...

  3.To modify an existing binding, select the binding and click Edit.

  4.To add a new binding, click Add...

  5.After you have set the unique bindings for the site, click OK, then click Close.
- Restart the Web site

  1.In IIS Manager, in the Connections pane, select the Web site that you have to start.

  2.In the Actions pane, click Stop to stop the site.

  3.In the Actions pane, click Start to start the site.